# ROS Answers SE migration: Removed distro

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just remove groovy, and now when i launch a new terminal it says :
/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash any file or folder of this kind.

So how can I stop ros from searching the disro groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188569/removed-distro/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove the `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` line from your `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

If you've upgraded to Hydro, you could also just update it to source the setup file for Hydro.

---

BTW: this has been asked (and answered) many times before. See for instance "[terminal starts with: bash: source/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash: No such file or directory](http://answers.ros.org/question/43602/terminal-starts-with-bash-sourceoptrosfuertesetupbash-no-such-file-or-directory/)" and "[ubuntu/ros error](http://answers.ros.org/question/125286/ubunturos-error/)". A Google search using ["no such file or directory" setup.bash site:answers.ros.org](https://www.google.nl/?q=%22no+such+file+or+directory%22+setup.bash+site:answers.ros.org) turns up many results.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2